# Relativistic energy density (dust, presureless gas or number of particles)

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The basic question on the relativistic energy density of the dust (pressureless gas or some number of moving particles). I assume that for some group of particles it is intuitively obvious to write the energy density as
$$e=\rho c^2 \: \gamma \tag{1}$$
just because that $e$ is the sum of the energies of all particles in the volume
(the volume is in the lab frame of reference)
$$e=\frac{n \: m  \: \gamma \: c^2  }{V}\tag{1a}$$
However, the definition of the stress-energy tensor says the energy density is the component
$$T^{00}= \rho (v^0) ^2=\rho c^2 \gamma^2 \tag{2}$$
which differs from (1). In order (2) to be correct one has to assume also multiplication of $(n \gamma) $ in (1a). Which expression for energy density is appropriate (1) or (2) then?

Comment: $T^{00}=\rho$ is $\textit{only}$ in the comoving frame reference [see Landau-Lifshiz, Hydtrodynamic] . In the lab reference frame it is $T^{00}=\rho v^0 v^0$ (if $p=0$).

Comment: In comoving frame it is obviously $v^0=1$, $v^i=0$ so $T^{00}=\rho c^2$,  $T^{ii}=-p$ and $T^{ij}=0$ ($i \neq j$), $i,j=1,2,3$. But the question is reg. lab frame

Comment: For dust $T^{\alpha \mu}=\rho v^{\alpha}v^{\mu}$. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_solution